# How to Validates an uploaded png image using PaperClip by its contents rather than its extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

My model looks like:

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "620x620>", :thumb => "200x200>" }
  validates_attachment :image, :content_type =>  { :content_type => "image/png" }
end
```

It validates and allows me to upload a PNG file png_file.png and does not allow me to upload a JPG file jpg_file.jpg.

But if I rename the PNG file to png_file.jpg it does not allow me to upload the image. And if I rename the JPG file to jpg_file.png it wrongly succeeds to upload the file.

I would like to know how can I validates the uploaded file by its real contents rather than the file extension. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the file in raw binary and check if it's of type PNG:

```
File.open('path-to-your-file', 'rb').read(9).include?('PNG')
```

The `9` is the [magic number of file](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html).

Comment: Just replaced the first read for an open and it worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yep. It was a typo.

Comment: File.open(tempfile){|f| f.read(9).include?('PNG') } - won't leak a file descriptor